# Looping through vector of dates in R drops class info

Tags: r, loops, date, vector

Here is my example.

```
my_df <- data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2), 
col_2 = c(as.Date('2018-11-11'), as.Date('2016-01-01')))
dates_list <- my_df$col_2
for(el in dates_list){
  print(el)
}
```

It generates:

```
17846
16801
```

How do I output dates instead? I can do it with explicit index, but would like to have simpler solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1)** Use `as.list`:

```
for(el in as.list(dates_list)) {
  print(el)
}
```

giving:

```
[1] "2018-11-11"
[1] "2016-01-01"
```

**2)** or not quite as nice but one can iterate over the indexes:

```
for(i in seq_along(dates_list)) {
  print(dates_list[i])
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Two great answers. `seq_along` is like `enumerate` in python, I did not know it existed in R

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `as_date` function from lubridate.

```
library(lubridate)

for(i in dates_list){
   print(as_date(i))
}

[1] "2018-11-11"
[1] "2016-01-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem could be that `dates_list <- my_df$col_2` coerces the column to a date vector:

```
dates_list <- my_df$col_2
class(dates_list)
> [1] "Date"
```

so another solution would be to resolve this, as follows:

```
dates_list <- my_df["col_2"]
class(dates_list)
[1] "data.frame"

for(el in dates_list){
    print(el)
}
[1] "2018-11-11" "2016-01-01"
```